# Update BQ E5 via apt-get

Tags: apt, updates, ubuntu-touch, phone

I've got an *BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition* phone.

Does updating and upgrading the phone via `apt-get` cover all the updates that Ubuntu provides via user-interface (as I know they do binary-differential-updates, i.e. something completely different)?
I am using the following commands:

```
sudo su
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get update
apt-get safe-upgrade
```

In other words: Can I replace the GUI-updates by the `apt-get` method?

I want to use `apt-get` since I am installing native Ubuntu programs such as `emacs` with `org-mode` and `latex`. The actual reason why I bought an Ubuntu phone is that I can use emacs with org-mode.

(See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640942/emacs-on-phone-e-g-bq-or-meizu) question.)

My first attempt looked very promising.
The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` containes the following. It looks like `apt-get` should do its job.

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-backports main restricted universe
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-backports main restricted universe

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security universe
# deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid-security multiverse
```

Maybe, the output of `uname -a` is helpful for answering this question:

```
# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-phablet 3.4.67 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 29 10:43:18 UTC 2015 8e13c5f armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```